How to acquire clip and rail systems for exterior cladding
I’m interested in using adhered veneer stone cladding in conjunction with ComfortBoard 80 on my foundation wall.  The attachment systems I’ve found appear to want you to be a contractor that they can “certify” as qualified to install the product.
Is there any way to acquire clip and rail systems on a more retail level? I suppose I can submit requests and see if I can get anyone to talk to me, but I need only a relative “handful” of product - I’m only cladding 30” of wall on a 180’ perimeter.
I suppose I could try to design my own system… or just use long tapcons that meet the necessary pullout length.
